# How to make a single div scroll down?

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I have been trying to make a div block have his own scroll, so basicly a div can scroll down while the others are not in movement. The error is that when I scroll down, the div moves up but the other divs are static and that makes it look ugly because all divs have a space between them, let me know if you need more explanation!

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="side-navbar">
        <h1>horse</h1>
        <h1>horse</h1>
        <h1>horse</h1>
        <h1>horse</h1>
        <h1>horse</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">
        <div class="news">
            <p>header next to side navbar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="user-content">
            <p>
                blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
                blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
                blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
                blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper .side-navbar {
      position: fixed;
      width: 200px;
      height: 97%;
      background: antiquewhite;
      padding: 30px 0;
      top: 5;
    }

    .wrapper .content-right {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 210px;
    }

    .wrapper .content-right .news {
      padding: 130px;
      background: red;
      position: fixed;
      width: 80%;
    }

    .wrapper .content-right .user-content {
      padding: 20px;
      background: red;
      margin-top: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

[image]
The idea is to have the div that is down in a single block, so that it has a margin-bottom like the side bar and that just that div scroll down

Comment: Do you want `user-content` div to scroll up and down while the rest divs remain fixed? In your example `user-content` is moving horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Display grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) makes layouts like these much easier.  For this layout, [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) could work just as well (and has better support), but the concept is the same - use a simpler layout.

All I did here was simplify the layout by removing `div.content-right`, using grid, and by using a simple reset (removes `margin`, `padding`, and changes the [`box model` to use the more intuitive `border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)).  I used the full (and verbose) grid rules, to help make following them a bit easier (there are much shorter versions).  I'm not entirely sure what your styles inside each of the regions are supposed to be, so I left them mostly alone (besides removing the styles made unnecessary by using a grid layout).

Stack overflow hates the `border-box` fix.  [Codepen shows it correctly.](https://codepen.io/DSMann/pen/695bd42c6a4599f4c47d17b61cfde98b?editors=1100)

```css
// simple reset
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper .side-navbar {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.wrapper .news {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  padding: 130px;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper .user-content {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side-navbar">
    <h1>horse</h1>
    <h1>horse</h1>
    <h1>horse</h1>
    <h1>horse</h1>
    <h1>horse</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <p>header next to side navbar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-content">
    <p>
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
      ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
      ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
      ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
      ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
      blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah
      blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Layouts are one of the most basic, and yet extremely frustrating things in CSS.  Learning how to make them as simple as possible goes a long way.

Comment: David thank you! your code helped me alot. the same process will be done if I want to add another block next to the blah one?

Comment: Next to it?  You'd need to add another column to `grid-template-columns` in `.wrapper` and adjust the `grid-column-end` for `.news`.  I'm not sure if that's the "same process", but it wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Thank you! I just did that using the same proces you opened my mind;)